# OOzie periodically kill a job

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue, oozie-coordinator

I have a infinite loop java program, which I want to start at a specific time and also kill after two hours , I can start the program, and it keeps on running, until I manually kill it, is there a way in Oozie(hue) where the job can be start and killed periodically ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a way to kill the action with a shell script (from an arbitrary node) you should be able to use the oozie shell action to kill it.

That being said, the way to go here would seem to be:

Pass an endtime to your loop (or a wrapper of your loop)

Comment: It is not part of the question, but you could also consider to run a cron job on all relevant nodes to kill the job.

Comment: The problem is I need to run the same program , in different workflows, for different period of time, that is why I can not specify a single endtime.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `<timeout>` option in the Oozie Coordinator... but the name is confusing: actually, that option does not apply to a *running* job.

I have used a **workaround** for a similar requirement: just tell the program when it is supposed to stop!

- in the Coordinator, generate a Workflow parameter with the *desired end time* for that execution, for instance "nominal start time +55 minutes" i.e. `${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), 55, 'MINUTE'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z')}`
- in the Workflow, pass that parameter as an argument to your Java program
- in the Java program, find a way to honor that *desired end time* argument -- i.e. if you run an infinite loop then `break` when the current time is over the limit, otherwise fork a dedicated thread with an infinite loop with a brutal `System.exit()`, etc.

Comment: BTW if your desired end time does not depend on "nominal Workflow start time" (because you want it to finish before the next execution is supposed to start),  but on "actual Action start time", then it's much simpler: just pass a fixed number of minutes as an argument to the Java program.